# Что такое статическая и что такое динамическая загрузка класса в Java?

Tags: java, классы, static, classloader, dynamic

Подскажите пожалуйста, что такое статическая и что такое динамическая загрузка класса в Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда стартует java приложение, все классы, которые так или иначе Ваше приложение создает через `new`, (те классы которые Вы импортируете директивой `import` и и те классы которые импортируются в тех классах которые Вы импортируете и так далее) будут загружены загрузчиком классов перед запуском приложения.

Это и есть статическая загрузка классов.

Также в java есть возможность загружать классы после старта, вызвав:

```
Class.forName("path.to.class.ClassName");
```

после чего можно будет создавать экземпляры этого класса через `Reflection Api`.

Это и есть динамическая загрузка.

---

Второй вариант является ненадежным с точки зрения целостности программы, так как Вам руками надо обеспечить попадание этого класса в область, в которой его увидит загрузчик классов, тогда как при статической загрузке это проверяет компилятор.

Однако это дает и огромные возможности по созданию действительно модульных систем, когда интерфейсы и их реализации разделены физически по разным jar, и jar c интерфейсом есть в изначальном приложении, а реализации может вообще еще не быть, классы могут быть загружены и выгружены динамически, без перезапуска основного процесса, что в свою очередь дает возможность строить гибкие приложения.

Comment: А можете рассказать про классы-загрузчики (ClassLoader) и про динамическую загрузку классов детальнее?

Comment: @ILYAYARATS это достаточно объемная тема, я подумаю что можно кще сюда добавить) но дучше бы вопрос был конкретный :)

Comment: `Однако это дает и огромные возможности по созданию действительно модульных систем, когда интерфейсы и их реализации разделены физически` что мешает это сделать без динамической загрузки?

Comment: @tym32167 я например про osgi, когда есть интерфейс, а реализацию еще завезли

Comment: ну если говорить конкретно о системах плагинов на стероидах, то да, имеет смысл. Думаю, лучше об этом явно написать, чтобы не создавалось впечатление, что без динамичской загрузки нельзя разделить интерфейс и имплементацию.

Comment: @tym32167 согласен, надо переформулировать